# How to correctly put in the C Drive correctly in Python

Tags: python, file, path, drive

I am trying to plug in the C drive to Python, but I keep getting this error.

[image: Image of problem]

What is the best way on how to solve this solution.

I tried to manually put it in and ^Z function to set it up but it won't work. I know it will work on the command prompt, but it won't work in Python 3. I am trying to use this to open up txt files.

Comment: That looks like an incorrect attempt at entering a shell command in the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the ":".

```py
import os
# This will create a text document "test.txt" in a folder called "temp" that is stored in the root directory of the C: drive.
with open(os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "temp", "tester.txt"), "w") as testdoc:
    testdoc.write("This is a test.")
```

You need the extra `os.sep` or python will not recognize the file structure correctly. You could also just use "C:\\" instead.

Note you may need to be in an elevated terminal (open a command prompt in administrator mode) depending on where the files you are trying to access are located.

**Edit:**
As @chepner points out, your example image shows the file structure pasted into a python interpreter. You will at least need quotes around it to treat it as a file path string. But it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish here so some more detail is needed to help.

If you are trying to open a file you can do this in python with...

```py
import os
with open(os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "Users", "User", "Desktop", "py4e", "filename.txt"), 'r') as file:
    # Do stuff with file, like file.readlines()
```

Comment: Did you look at the image in the question? This doesn't seem to be related at all.